Using VEML6070 sensor on STM32H750B
I am trying to write a function that uses the VEML6070 sensor for the STM32H750B board but cant figure out what I am doing wrong, I am using the sensor on the UV3 Click from MikroE and keep getting the error MSB fail
My function below:
void getUV(void) {
#define VEML6070_ADDR_CMD 0x38 <<1
#define VEML6070_ADDR_DATA_LSB 0x38 << 1
#define VEML6070_ADDR_DATA_MSB 0x73
#define VEML6070_CMD_IT_2T 0x0C

uint8_t address;
uint8_t cmd = VEML6070_CMD_IT_2T;
uint8_t msb;
uint8_t lsb;
uint8_t data;


HAL_StatusTypeDef ret = HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&hi2c4, VEML6070_ADDR_CMD, Trials, Timeout);
          if (ret != HAL_OK)
          {
              snprintf(SendBuffer4, sizeof(SendBuffer4), "Device not ready");

          }else{

                 ret = HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c4, VEML6070_ADDR_CMD, cmd, 1, 1000);
                HAL_Delay(300);
                             if ( ret != HAL_OK ) {
                                 snprintf(SendBuffer4, sizeof(SendBuffer4), "Test Not Sent");
                             }else{
                                ret = HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c4, VEML6070_ADDR_DATA_MSB,(uint8_t*)&msb, 1, 1000);
                                                 if (ret != HAL_OK){
                                                    snprintf(SendBuffer4, sizeof(SendBuffer4), "MSB missing");
                                                 }else{
                                                    ret = HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c4, VEML6070_ADDR_DATA_LSB,(uint8_t*)&lsb, 1, 1000);
                                                                     if (ret != HAL_OK){
                                                                        snprintf(SendBuffer4, sizeof(SendBuffer4), "LSB missing");
                                                                     }else{

                                                                        data = (msb << 8) | lsb;
                                                                        snprintf(SendBuffer4, sizeof(SendBuffer4), "UV Index: %u", data);
                                                                     }
                                                 }

                             }

             }

          }

I tried everything I could think of but I am still a novice and reading and understanding the datasheet is hard. I tried different commands with and without Initialization different addresses etc.

Almost all HAL I2C functions require you to shift the I2C address left by one bit when passing it as an argument.

The I2C address for VEML6070_ADDR_DATA_MSB should be 0x39 << 1.

When I set the address to 0x38 <<1 I start getting readings but as soon as the sensor gets hit with light I get the error MSB missing and it stays that way even if I restart the app I dont know what I am doing wrong maybe I need to do the Initialization differently
